# noob learning cisco

Tags: cisco, switch, router, ping

I'm trying to teach myself how to use cisco devices. i was given an router, switch and firewall. so far i been able to set up vlan and have intra vlan routing working. My issue is having the switch ping my firewall (or any devices at 192.168.1.1). i have been going around in circles trying to get it working. Any help or advice would be appreciated.

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30 overload
!
ip access-list standard NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
!

interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20
 ip address 192.168.20.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30
 encapsulation dot1Q 30
 ip address 192.168.30.1 255.255.255.0
 ip nat inside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 ip address 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0
 ip nat outside
 ip virtual-reassembly in
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 no ip address
 shutdown
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list NAT_ACL interface GigabitEthernet0/0.30 overload
!
ip access-list standard NAT_ACL
 permit 192.168.10.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 192.168.20.0 0.0.0.255
 permit 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255
```

Comment: I don't see any routes configured in your config, and 192.168.1.0/24 is not directly connected. You need to specify how to reach that network.

Comment: thanks. i'll look into it now and see where i have made an error :)

Comment: tried a few things but no luck. 

Switch(config)#ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.1

Comment: You seem to have pasted the firewall config twice so we can't see any switch config.

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet0/24
switchport trunk encapsulation dot1q
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,20,30
switchport mode trunk
interface Vlan1
no ip address
interface Vlan10
ip address 192.168.10.2 255.255.255.0
interface Vlan20
ip address 192.168.20.2 255.255.255.0
interface Vlan30
ip address 192.168.30.2 255.255.255.0
ip default-gateway 192.168.30.1
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.30.1